# Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/libusb

Tags: homebrew, libusb

Running

```
$ brew doctor
```

gives me:

```
Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
```

According to this [Linking libusb in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416827/linking-libusb-in-mac-os-x) I should run `brew upgrade libusb` however when doing so I get:

```
$ brew upgrade libusb
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/libusb
```

Any suggestions how I upgrade? Or, simpler, to uninstall if it's not necessary. What's it used for?

Comment: Do you _need_ `libusb`? If you just want to fix the `Unexpected dylibs` warning you can just remove the file. If you want to _install_ `libusb` run `brew install libusb`.